# ImGui Watermark/Overlay?

Tags: c++, user-interface, overlay, watermark, imgui

I want to make a Watermark/permanent Overlay for my ImGui. It should look like at the left corner in the picture. How can I do that?[Left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyM0l.png)

Answer (score 3):

The Dear ImGui Demo has exactly this example in "Demo -> Examples > Simple overlay".